# Updating map after updating standalone tables with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv, update, standalone

I am using ArcGIS Pro and have added a CSV file called 'Period 1' as a standalone table and mapped its destinations in my project. And now, I have a new version of 'Period 1' file after data cleaning.

Can I update the standalone table for 'Period 1' in ArcGIS Pro and update the map automatically?

Here is the way I added the data into ArcGIS Pro: I dragged the CSV file into ArcGIS Pro and then the CSV file shows as a standalone table in ArcGIS Pro. Then, I clicked 'Add Data' ---> 'XY Point Data' to map all the destinations.

Comment: You might add some more information.  The answer may hinge on how you added that table and used it in the map, including what "mapped its destinations" involves.

Comment: I dragged the CSV file into ArcGIS Pro and then the CSV file shows as a standalone table in ArcGIS Pro. Then, I clicked 'Add Data'  ---> 'XY Point Data' to map all the destinations.

Answer (score 2):

A Standalone table in ArcGIS Pro is different to the CSV file.

The data will be stored in the Geodatabase now.

If it's linked to the features via a Join you might be able to open the geodatabase **in a different project**, add the CSV file again (with the same name) then reopen the original project and see if the join still works.

If you have made a new feature class with the CSV data it won't work but you could try copying the data from your new CSV to the Feature class (this is how I have done it - but via a python script)

Have a read about joins here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/tables/joins-and-relates.htm